# Create bootable Linux pendrive that can be booted on Windows and Mac

Tags: linux, windows, macos, usb

How do I create a bootable linux pendrive that can be booted on a PC (windows) and iMac (Mac) using the same usb? installing linux with unetbootin doesn't work for imacs...

Answer (score 0):

You can try LinuxLiveUSBCreator. I haven't tried it for Mac though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/), pretty good tool which supports almost every Linux flavor.